# Remove empty list from a list of lists

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists where some of them are `NA` e.g. `empty lists`. I want to extract all the lists which are filled with data and remove all the lists which are `empty(NA)`.

The code i'm trying is:

```
lapply(outputfile,function(x){
  if(outputfile != NA){
  test<-lapply(outputfile,unlist)
}})
```

But this does not work.

The list of lists is like this: (small example of random data)

```
list(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, list(c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)))
```

I only want to extract the list with the 5s in it. The first 6 lists should be ignored e.g. removed.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `l[!is.na(l)]` (to remove NA's at the first level)?

Comment: @Arun thanks, sometimes i dont realise how simple it could be:S

Comment: @Arun even though it's simple, maybe you should add that as answer so it can be marked and removed from unanswered Q's?

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw, are all "empty" lists indicated by `NA`? What about a list like: `List <- list(A = NA, B = 1:10, C = vector("character"))`? Would `List$C` be considered "empty"?

Comment: @AnandaMahto All the empty list are filled with NA, because the list are all coming from the same calculation.

Comment: @SimonO101, yes, done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, to remove `NA` at the first level, you could use `is.na` directly:

```
l[!is.na(l)]
```

Alternatively, you can also use `Filter` which tries to coerce the results of the evaluated function to logical and returns those elements that evaluated to TRUE. You could do, for example:

```
Filter(function(x) !is.na(x), l)
```

(or) equivalently (as @flodel writes under comment)

```
Filter(Negate(is.na), l)
```

Comment: or `Filter(Negate(is.na), l)`

Comment: @Arun which of the 2 will be the fastest? I did a `system.time` on both the functions and the 1st was the fastest. But that is with 3000 `lists`.

Comment: @flodel, yes indeed! brilliant!

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw, yes, I would think the first would be faster. But the ease to understand the code with the 2nd is better. And I don't think there is usually much performance loss.

Comment: Similarly, I used this to remove empty elements: `Filter(function(k) length(k)>0, mylist)` .  Well done!