# Remove elements in list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

there is an R list which has sublists - i am indexing with list[[i]] - some from these lists are empty - they are just NULL. How can I remove these and just keep those in which a matrix is stored?

```
list[[1]]
 [1,]   99   45
  [2,]   92   45
  [3,]   11   45
  [4,]   99   45
  [5,]   92   45
  [6,]   99    2
  [7,]   99   22
  [8,]   99    2
```

that is okay but

```
list[[4]] NULL
```

think

```
delete.NULLs  <-  function(x.list){   # delele null/empty entries in a list
    x.list[unlist(lapply(x.list, length) != 0)]
}
```

would work, but that is very slow. My list has 40 million sublists, and I suppose most of them are not having numbers...

Comment: this should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292904/remove-empty-list-from-a-list-of-lists

Comment: but this is for NA..not NULL

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Filter`. For example:

```
my_list <- list(A = 10, B = NULL, C = rnorm(10), D = NULL)

#remove nulls
Filter(Negate(is.null), my_list)
```

Comment: this is the good approach :) I delete my answer, you were quickest at 20 sec